# How to do this query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select, logical-operators

SELECT `item_name` from items WHERE `item_id` = $var;

I tried:

$var = 001 || 002 || 003 || 004;

$var = 001 OR 002 OR 003 OR 004;

$var = 001 or 002 or 003 or 004;

But all do not work.

Thanks, i try that, but the output only 1 result => 1.

What I want is to output all, i.e. 1, 2 , 3 and 4.. Means, I want to select multiple records(rows) from 1 column

How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select multiple records (row) from a column in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544750/how-to-select-multiple-records-row-from-a-column-in-mysql)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT item_name from items WHERE item_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

And if `item_id` is a `VARCHAR` for some reason:

```
SELECT item_name from items WHERE item_id IN ('001', '002', '003', '004')
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use:

SELECT item_name from items WHERE item_id = 001 OR item_id = 002 etc.

Answer (score 1):

the correct SQL sintax would be:

```
SELECT item_name from items WHERE item_id = 001 or item_id = 002 or item_id=003;
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got bigger problems than the question you've posed.  The query you are trying to write is trivial and the fact that you are a little lost with it is not good.

If I were you, I'd take a step back and review a couple tutorials on sql.  Spend a few hours (or a few days) learning the topic before proceeding.

Of course, you could just try to 'get the task done', but you will likely have significant security and/or performance issues with the queries you write.

There are a lot of good tutorials out there.  Go read them.

Good luck!