# How to select multiple records (row) from a column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select

I want to display four (4) items'name from these id:
Can I do like this?

```
SELECT item_name from items WHERE item_id IN ('001', '012', '103', '500')
```

or

```
SELECT item_name from items WHERE item_id = '001' or item_id = '012' or item_id = '103' or item_id = '500'
```

**IN RESPONSE TO ALL ANSWERS**

Well, most of the answers said it works, but it does not really work. Here is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT `item_name` from items WHERE item_id IN('s001','a012','t103','p500')";

$result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die (mysql_error());
$fetch =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die (mysql_error());
$itemsCollected = $fetch['item_name'];
echo $itemsCollected;
```

The `item_id` is alphanumeric.

Comment: Sure, both of those should work. It's easy to test this, why don't you just try it?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544673/how-to-do-this-query-in-mysql, also asked by you, and there's no real question here as it is totally possible to do what you're asking and 1 second trying it would show you. Voting to close.

Comment: Tried many times, only 1 result. Thats why I am posting this question

Comment: It does not work.. I need help urgently..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do either one, but the IN query is much more efficient for this purpose for any large queries. I did some simple testing long ago that revealed it's about 10 times faster to use the IN construct for this. If you're asking if the syntax is correct then yes, it looks fine, other than missing semi-colons to complete the statement.

**EDIT**: It looks like the actual question you were asking was "why do these queries only return one value". Well, looking at the sample code you posted, the problem is here:

```
$fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die (mysql_error());
$itemsCollected = $fetch['item_name'];
echo $itemsCollected;
```

You need to loop through and iterate until there are no more results to be fetched, as [Pax pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544750/how-to-select-multiple-records-row-from-a-column-in-mysql/544757#544757). See the PHP manual page for [**mysql_fetch_assoc**](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc):

```
$sql = "SELECT item_name from items WHERE item_id IN('s001','a012')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

// While a row of data exists, put that row in $row as an associative array
// Note: If you're expecting just one row, no need to use a loop
// Note: If you put extract($row); inside the following loop, you'll
//       then create $userid, $fullname, and $userstatus
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, both those should work fine. What's the actual problem you're seeing?

If, as you say, only one record is being returned, try:

```
select item_name from items order by item_id
```

and check the full output to ensure you have entries for 001, 012, 103 and 500.

If **both** those queries only return one row, I would suspect not.

If they all do exist, check the table definitions, it may be that the column is CHAR(4) and contains spaces for the others. You may have genuinely found a bug in MySQL but I doubt it.

After EDIT:

This is a perl/mysql problem, not an SQL one: `mysql_fetch_array()` returns **only one** row of the dataset at a time and advances a pointer to the next.

You need to do something like:

```
$query = "SELECT item_name from items WHERE item_id IN('s001','a012')";
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die (mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["item_name"];
}
```

Comment: only 1 result. i.e display the id 001 only

Comment: Right, so that's probably the number of rows with those item_id's. Do 012, 103 and 500 exist in the table?

Comment: Do a "SELECT item_name from items order by item_id" and check.

Comment: all the id exists in the database

Answer (score 0):

Your ID field must be set to auto increment, i guess. i had problems with that once and i changed the auto increment to int. in the IN field if you pass the parameters to match against the auto increment variable you get back only the first parameter, the remaining generates an error.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the mysql_num_rows function to tell you how many rows your query retrieved and then use that result to increment a for loop. An example.

```
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query_results);
for ($i=0; $i <$num_rows ; $i++) { 
    $query_array[]=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_results);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to get the query and assign the values from `mysql_fetch_assoc` query into a an array. Simple as that

```
$i=0;
$fullArray = array();

$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id='111' OR id='112' OR id='113' ")or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    foreach ($row as $value) {
        $fullArray[$i] = $value;
    }
    $i++;
}

var_dump($fullArray); 

echo $fullArray[0]."<br/>".$fullArray[1]."<br/>".$fullArray[2];`
```